# Change references to question marks when I use a multiply-defined label

Tags: cross-referencing

LaTeX's default behaviour for a multiply-defined label is to overwrite the existing label. This makes it hard to notice errors when I am proof-reading. Is there any way to force LaTeX to store these references as a question mark instead of overwriting them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
  1 \label{eq} \\
  2 \label{eq}
\end{align}
\eqref{eq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Multi defined labels are already listed in the log.

Comment: It is not difficult to change the reference text to question marks as soon as the label is defined a second time, but this will then affect only any later references, or those before the first `\label` command, but not those between the first and the second `\label`. So you would not notice the problem when referencing the label between the two definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Labels are saved as global macros.  For example, `\label{eq}` is saved as `\r@eq`.  These macros are created by `\newlabel` when the aux file is read.

Note that packages like `hyperref` and `cleveref` replace `\newlabel` with something more complicated.

Personally, I would have gone with `\textcolor{red}{XXX}`, but you asked for `??`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\@newl@bel#1#2#3{{%
  \@ifundefined{#1@#2}%
  {\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}%
  {\gdef \@multiplelabels {%
  \@latex@warning@no@line{There were multiply-defined labels}}%
  \@latex@warning@no@line{Label ‘#2’ multiply defined}%
  \global\@namedef{#1@#2}{{??}{\@secondoftwo#3}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
  1 \label{eq} \\
  2 \label{eq}
\end{align}
\eqref{eq}

\noindent page \pageref{eq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. If I'm using `hyperref`, should I replace the `\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{#3}}` with `\global\@namedef{#1@#2}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}{\@currentlabelname}{\@currentHref}{}}`?

Comment: Right idea, but `\@currentlabel` etc are simply part of #3 at this point.  What you need is something like `\@secondoftwo` for the remaining 4 arguments.  `\def\newlabelargs#1#2#3#4#5{{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}` should do it.